# devise user from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, console

I am trying to create a devise user using rails console with the below method

```
User.create!({:email => "abc@gmail.com", :roles => ["admin"], :password => "abc123", :password_confirmation => "abc123" })
```

I am not able to understand If the user is created or not. After I hit enter command I do not get any respond. I did `user.save` and then did `u.all` but it shows nothing and I am not able to login.

Please suggest what's wrong.

Edit: I am trying below as well but it is not working

```
@user = User.new(:email => 'test@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
@user.save
```

Thanks

Comment: There are no objects `user` or `u`. So both `user.save` and `u.all` should throw error. To get all users do `User.all` or to get last user `User.last`

Comment: ok, but `User.create` is not creating any user anyways, Is that syntax wrong?

Comment: whats the error in console after User.create?

Comment: It goes to the next line without any error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATED: 
You are missing the {} in your User.new()

```
user = User.new({email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'})
user.save
```

---

Do you have :confirmable option on? If yes, do:

```
user = User.new({email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'})
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

Comment: I get this `NoMethodError: undefined method `skip_confirmation!' for #<User:0x000000059da620>
` when I hit second command for skip notification

Comment: yes, It works, thanks. How can I give that user a role as admin?>

Comment: @Suraj i just updated the answer. For your role, you can do user.role = "admin" user.save

Comment: that gives same error. no method error
` user.role = "admin"`

Comment: my bad, it should be user.roles = "admin"

Comment: or according to your syntax, user.roles = ["admin'] user.save